# Like SUMIF for text, is there a function in Google Sheets to combine alphanumeric values given a common ID?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns, one of order reference numbers and one with their associated store IDs. I need to take that data and combine the order reference numbers into a single cell for each given store id, similar to using SUMIF to total all the sales for a given store.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of what you need?

Comment: For example, if I have two columns, 
StoreID {123, 234, 123}     
OrderID {ACB123, ACB789,  ACB987}

and I wanted to get all the OrderIDs for Store 123, the cell might look like this: "ACB123, ACB987". It would have two values joined together because StoreID 123 had two Order IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Store ids in A and Order Ids in B, this formula in cell G2:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

and this formula in cell H2, then dragged down the length of column H

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(A:A,B:B=G2)))
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!